# Java 11 - java.util.date - now sending date in unix timestamp

Tags: java, spring, upgrade, java-11

I have been working on a Java 8 legacy platform and we utilize the java.util.date Date object in our DTOs to respond to API requests.

Ex: we would have a getWidget() endpoint in our API that someone would hit and we would return a responseWidgetDto that would have a variable that is a Date object.

```
public class WidgetResponseDTO{
  private Long id;
  **private Date startDate;**
  private String name;
}
```

In the response JSON, this would be a String Date.  There is no code that's formatting the Date object. Just responding with a raw Date.
(actual JSON from our Java 8 platform)

[image: JSON with Date as string]

**The problem:**

We have been upgrading the platform to Java 11 over the last few months and we found that the Date object is now showing in the JSON as a Unix timestamp:

[image]

We haven't changed any code, other than upgrading to compile with Java 11. I have been searching online, but I can't find anything that may indicate why this has occurred.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: Assuming you are using spring-boot you can modify how dates are converted, try using **spring.jackson.date-format=yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss** in your application.properties.

Comment: @JonnathanQ - unfortunately, we're using Spring, not Spring Boot so that is not an option. No application.properties file.

Comment: Try providing a custom object mapper, take a look at https://javadeveloperzone.com/spring/spring-jackson-custom-date-format/

Comment: Thanks, that does work.  I'm curious as to why it used to send the date in a String pattern in Java 8 and after the upgrade, it sends the Date in a unix time stamp and requires manual input on our part to provide the pattern. We use Date in A LOT of places and it's going to be pain to go through and do this everywhere.

Comment: Well, that is actually a really good question and I have no idea, no body would expect this behavior.

Comment: @JonnathanQ Should you post that as a helpful answer?

Comment: @OleV.V. - JonnathanQ provided a workaround to the problem, but didn't really answer the question.  Why did Java start sending Date objects as unix time stamps after the Java 8 > 11 upgrade when it used to send them as patterned strings in J8?